# iOS app with only launch feature will it clear store review?

Tags: ios, itunes-store

I am tying to launch an iOS app for my website. Planned to start development few months later but like to have my app on store immediately with a small functionality of launching my app would open the mWeb directly with my site url.

So will this app be accepted in app store review?

Comment: Probably not. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality (2.12)

Comment: if you only open the url and do not provide further functionality then no, it will not be allowed.

Comment: Ohh ok! If i have a login/sign up page then move to mWeb, will that work?

Comment: Apple policies aside, this is a bad idea.  Users will hate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suggest Apple would reject it.

To quote the [**app store review guidelines**](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as
>   Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be
>   rejected.

Comment: Thanks Ducan!
So if i have a login/sign up page then move to mWeb, will that work?

Comment: Apple can be hard to predict. Read the app review guidelines I posted in my answer, and then it is still a bit of a crapshoot.

Comment: "So if i have a login/sign up page then move to mWeb, will that work" the answer is DEFINITELY NO.  it is tried 1000s of times a month and they SPECIFICALLY REJECT THOSE.  the answer IS NO, for better or worse.

Comment: Thank you Joe! Will try to add few features.